# On the latter day of the law and Nikko Shonin

Tags: mahayana, nichiren

I have realised the importance of establishing a trinity in Buddhism (via the mentor disciple relationship). I'd like to learn why Nikko Shonin was unable to do so in the latter day of the law despite being Nicheren's direct disciple?

Comment: Nevermind ... I figured out the answer

Comment: I don't think he failed. He managed to establish a continuity despite the latter day